# How can I make queried column dynamic, as per what's entered in the column header to be populated?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, google-query-language

Right now, I can populate a sheet with data queried and that gets the destination column header name dynamically, using this:

```
=query(
Scenarios!A5:FQ,
"select "&REGEXEXTRACT(ADDRESS(5,MATCH(B2,Scenarios!A5:5,0)),"[A-Z]+")&"
 where "&REGEXEXTRACT(ADDRESS(5,MATCH("PO #",Scenarios!A5:5,0)),"[A-Z]+")&" = 
 '"&$B$13&"'",0)
```

How can I use a similar approach when in this case?

```
=vlookup(AB9,Scenarios!A:BL,64,FALSE)
```

[Here is an example of the data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit?usp=sharing)

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share an example sheet publicly with dummy data to see how you have it now?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Just did it, @Kessy! Thank you!

Comment: Just did it, @player0! Thank you for always helping so many people here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see:

```
=FILTER(A7:C; REGEXMATCH(A7:C7; "Region|Rep"))
```

[image]

if order of columns matters:

```
=QUERY(FILTER(A7:C; REGEXMATCH(A7:C7; "Region|Rep")); "select Col2,Col1")
```

[image]

or you can try:

```
=INDEX(VLOOKUP(ROW(A7:A); {ROW(A7:A)\ B7:C}; {3\ 2}; 0))
```

[image]

or like:

```
=INDEX(VLOOKUP(ROW(A7:A); {ROW(A7:A)\ B7:C}; MATCH({"Rep"\ "Region"}; A7:C7; 0); 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Otherworldly...from Kepler - 22b! Thank you!